# cannot create executables gcc: ./specs is a directory

Tags: gcc, gcc4, specs

I am trying to compile libXaw-1.0.10 , and while configuring i get:
gcc: ./specs is a directory

I tried to compile a basic helloworld.c and when i created "specs" directory, my compilation failed!

- What is the cause for this behaviour ?

[this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-05/msg00301.html)  solves the issue , but why gcc is unable to ignore ":" at the end of (library & ld_library )path file list?

Comment: That's a bug in GCC they should fix, I guess... So annoying. :)